# How does one reask something that has changed since it was previously asked?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

Ive been sorting by most votes on questions and occasionally come across something for 2014. <s>Usually</s> Sometimes these articles end with "we dont know but probe X in 1-3 years will give us that information!"

If I would like to request an update on an existing question based on new information, is it better to ask in a comment or repost the question with the original linked?

Comment: or edit the question?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a bounty option for that.

Comment: I've done both; for me it depends on the specifics such as how active or profoundly inactive the person who would receive notification for the aforementioned comment, as well as how much the situation or topic has changed in the interim. Consider citing an example or three, and or consider just trying one or the other and see what happens?